# Windows - multiple concurrent unattended installations

Tags: windows, unattended, tftp, windows-pe

Distribution Server and Software:

```
Debian 8
TFTP Server
SAMBA Server
DHCP Server
```

Right now we use following way for windows (2012) distribution to our servers:

- installation task inkomming
- edit dhcp server (new server)
- auto create wim boot image (via debian server, modification of wim template via [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/))
- create samba share with unattended.xml
- power on pc
- dhcp request of new server
- tftp download of wim (winpe) image
- winpe boot and mount of sambsa share
- unattended installation of windows

this works as expected - but the tftp download is limited to one fix source `{TFTPSource}/Boot/startrom.0`

Becouse of the limitation of the path, right now its only possible to start one windows installation at time until the load of the wim image is done. after the wim image is done the next installation can be triggered.

now we searched for a "better" way to install multiple windows servers at once.
We found several projekts like [OPSI](http://www.opsi.org/en) or [Unattended](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unattended/) but none of them seems to fit our requirements:

OPSI seems to need a software on the client, which is permament on the client. It seems there is no official support for Windows Server 2016 Distribution.

Unattended seems only for Windows 2000 / XP / 2003.

We would need (it could be a windows deploeyment server at all) a deployment server, which can deliver multiple clients at once (unattended installation based on a unattended template, which we will edit before the installation)

What is the right way to deliver windows server 2012 (2016, and maybe other windows distributions) onto multiple clients?

Is there a free windows software (preferable remote controllable with commandline) for this need?

Maybe there is a way to modify the fix coded path `{TFTPSource}/Boot/startrom.0` of the windows Bootrom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simultaneously install Windows and Linux assets with [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html).

You can also use Microsoft tools like WDS/MDT (free) and SCCM (non-free); MS tools require MS Server as host.

Comment: WDS is our choise right now, thanks for your information.